# Change the Fill and Stroke color of an area chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, visualization

I am relatively new to google charts, so please pardon my ignorance;

I am looking at the Area Chart, and I want to change the Fill and Stroke color. Here is the code...

```
<!--
You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>
            Google Visualization API Sample
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function drawVisualization() {
                // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Month',   'Target'],
                    ['JAN',    85],
                    ['FEB',    105],
                    ['MAR',    65],
                    ['APR',    45],
                    ['MAY',    45],
                    ['JUN',    15],
                    ['JUL',    60]
                ]);

                // Create and draw the visualization.
                var ac = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
                ac.draw(data, {
                    title : '',
                    isStacked: true,
                    width: 600,
                    height: 400,
                    vAxis: {title: "Millions"},
                    hAxis: {title: "Month"}
                });
            }

            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
        <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The other part of my question is, where can I find a complete reference for customizing google charts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fill and stroke color of each series in the AreaChart is determined by the series color.  You can set the color of data series by setting the `colors` option (which takes an array of HTML color strings, assigned to data series in column order) or via the `series.<series index>.color` option (which takes an HTML color string:

```
colors: ['#f36daa', 'blue', '#3fc26b']
```

or:

```
series: {
    0: {
        // set options for the first data series
        color: '#f36daa'
    },
    1: {
        // set options for the second data series
        color: 'red'
    },
    2: {
        // set options for the third data series
        color: '#3fc26b'
    }
}
```

Chart options are (mostly) documented in the documentation for the specific chart (eg: [AreaChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#Configuration_Options)).  Some features that span multiple charts are documented separately (eg: [Intervals](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/intervals), [Trendlines](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/trendlines), [Dashboards and Controls](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls), [Event Handlers](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events), [Animations](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation)).  Data structures, data manipulation, formatting, and associated classes are documented in the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference).